# How to get all images(overlapping allowed) in one line using css?

Tags: html, css, width, inline, nowrap

I have a few images(3) which should be displayed in one line and whose combined width is MORE than the page width. But i anyway want them be overlapping, hence the page width doesn't matter. But for some reason only 2 images are coming in one line and third in the next. How do i sort this out.
They work perfectly if i make `.imageContainer` as `position:abolute` and give `left:--px` values to each of the id. But that would be difficult to maintain and align. Also they align up properly if i reduce the width of each image, but i don't want to do that :( . Please Help.

---

**UPDATE**
`white-space:nowrap;` placed in allImagesContainer has solved this problem, but only in chrome. The problem persists in FF and IE.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="allImagesContainer">
<div class="imageContainer" id="firstImage">
    <img  src="images/android1.png"/>
    <div class="innerText"></div>
</div>

<div class="imageContainer" id="biggerImage" >
    <img src="images/android2.png"/>
    <div class="innerText"></div>
</div>

<div class="imageContainer" id="lastImage">
    <img src="images/android3.png"/>
    <div class="innerText"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here's the styling:

```
.allImagesContainer {
position: relative;
top: 50px;
width: 80%;
height: 500px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: table ;
}

.imageContainer{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

#firstImage{
z-index: 1;
}

#biggerImage{
position: relative;
left: -50px;
z-index: 2;
}

#lastImage{
position: relative;
left: -40px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`white-space:nowrap;` is what you're looking for, placed in `allImagesContainer`

See a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/rZMNh/)

Comment: Sadly its not working for Firefox or IE. I am having the exact same problem as i used to in chrome before adding `white-space:nowrap` in `allImagesContainer`. Any suggestion?

Comment: See if the demo i added to my answer works for you in those browsers. It is working for me in Firefox 17.0.1 and ie9. Which browser versions are you using?

Comment: FF- 19.02 and IE9.0. Also your demo works fine in all the browsers. As i said, the problem is when the image width is more.....the third image then wraps down below the first two images (but your demo works perfectly even for huge images.)

Comment: Since the demo works with all image widths on all browsers, yet not with your code, perhaps some other style is interfering.

Comment: hmmm, I'll check, but the code I submitted is almost the whole code.....except for a header and a footer (which is not interfering with the styling). Anyway, thanks.

Comment: In that case, have you declared a DTD (i.e. <!DOCTYPE...>)? If not, try declaring <!DOCTYPE html> at the top of your code.

Comment: yes I have.
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: Try just <!DOCTYPE html>, which is the HTML5 definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want line breaks, you can use this css on allImagesContainer

```
.allImagesContainer
{
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Your can remove the position: absolute and relative on all the elements but keep the display:inline-block

Comment: Yeah, thanks that works. But i dont want to remove relative/absolute as i want them to overlap. Thanks again.

Comment: It worked perfectly for chrome. But is not working for any others (tried for FF and IE). Help.